# Object type with partial definition flowjs

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

Say I had a function:

```
const example = (item : ?{+type?: ?string}) : {+result: ?string} => {
  const state = {}
  state.result = item.result
  return state
}
```

This fails to typecheck with:

```
 12:         state.result = item.result
                                    ^^^^^^^ property `result`. Property not found in
 12:         state.result = item.result
                             ^^^^^^ object type
```

Why doesn't this typecheck? I did not define the type with the exact object type notation `?{|+type?: ?string|}`, so shouldn't it allow additional keys? How does the exact object notation work then? And how can I define partial object types like this? Is that even possible?

Comment: Your argument, `item` doesn't have a property called `result`. Did you mean to write `state.result = item.type` instead? (though you'll also need a null check there).

Comment: no sorry if my question is unclear, feel free to edit. I mean that there may be many keys in this object, not all of which I can possibly enumerate, and I don't understand why flow is failing to typecheck given that I did not use the "exact object" notation. Any way I could clarify the question (feel free to edit by the way!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to encode in types that the argument `item` can have *any* properties. This sounds like a map, which Flow encodes with:

```
{ [key: KeyType]: ValueType };
```

Your example can be updated like this:

```
const example = (item : ?{[key: string]: string}) : {+result: ?string} => {
  const state = {}
  if(item)
  {
     state.result = item.result;
  }
  return state
}
```

Note, you have to do a null check on `item` or else it won't typecheck, since you declared it as nullable in the function signature.

If there are certain required properties of `item` then you can use an intersection type to add that constraint. I'll create a new type for that, so it's easier to read the signature:

```
type Item = {[key: string]: string} & {type: string}

const example = (item : ?Item) : {+result: ?string} => {
  const state = {}
  if(item)
  {
     state.result = item.result;
  }
  return state
}


example({type: 'blah', x: '2'}); // OK
example({'blah', x: '2'}); // Error: type is missing
```

Comment: is it possible to enforce the presence of some keys in item, if it exists?

Comment: One question that I still don't quite understand hte answer to, what is the exact object notation useful for if not this?

Comment: The exact object notation is this part: `{type: string}`. But I also combined it with the map type using `&`, to say: It can have **any** string properties, but it **must** have a `type` property.

Comment: right but I guess what I'm not understanding is what the meaning of the exact object notation even is. I thought that the difference was that:

{foo: string} accepts only objects containing a key foo, while {| foo: string |} accepts only objects containing ONLY a key foo... this is clearly not true so I am somewhat confused as to the difference between them

Comment: Let's say you have a function, `foo(x: {type: string})`. You can call it with any object that has a `type` property, even if it has other other properties too. However, the function itself can only use `x.type` - it can't use the object's other properties because it doesn't know what they are. But if the argument is of type `{[key: string]: string})` then it's a map and there are no constraints on which keys it might have.

Comment: I see. What if it were an arbitrarily complex map, where the value of some keys were unknown? Would that be a usecase for any?

Comment: Yes. Or you could use disjoint unions:  `{[key: string]: string|boolean|number })` if you know what types they can be.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my (many!) questions